# Problem with finding an id after generating it in a loop

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 14, and I have a function that creates new elements in a loop. Each element is assigned a unique id by combining the word "card" with the index number.

After generating all the ids, I attempt to access the elements using getElementById, but it always returns null.

Here are the steps I have taken to troubleshoot the issue:

1.I searched the web and Stack Overflow for solutions but couldn't find any helpful information.
2.I used console.log to check the card.id after it was generated, and it appeared fine.
3.I even tried manually passing a valid id as a string instead of using an argument, but it still returns null.
Here is a snippet of how I generate the ids:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.visibleCards.length; i++) {
  const cardV = this.visibleCards[i];

  // Create card element
  const card = document.createElement('div');
  alert(card.id); // Shows nothing
  card.setAttribute("id", 'card' + i);
  alert(card.id); // Shows 'card0', 'card1', 'card2', etc.
  card.classList.add('card');

  // ...more code

  this.appendAmountToCardDetails(i);

}
```

The appendAmountToCardDetails function is where I encounter the issue:

```
appendAmountToCardDetails(cardNumber: number) {
  const cardId = 'card' + cardNumber;
  const card = document.getElementById(cardId); // Returns null in the debugger and developer tools
  const cardDetails = document.querySelector('#' + cardId + ' .card-details') as HTMLElement;

  // ...rest of the code
}
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to receive the element by id and avoid getting null as the result.

Comment: So where are the newly generated elements actually getting appended to the DOM?

Comment: You are not adding the new element to the DOM at any time. So you simply cannot acces it with `getElementById`

Comment: in card.setattrbuite("id", ...etc .. ) also i used alert to check its id and i can see the id.
if i try to find the elemnt id inside the function where i create the card id i can find it and it works fine

Comment: in the rest of the code i append the card to the dom

Comment: And if you want to display, some object or array in angular from your component.ts you should use Angular syntax in your component.html.Most of the time you don't have to manipulate the DOM manually, it's not the purpose of angular. you should do something like that in your component.html : `<div *ngFor='let card of visibleCards' [id]='card.card.id' class="card">{{card.card_id}}</div>`

Comment: Yes, I imagined that there would be people who would try to fix the structure of the code, I asked for help with something else and you try to show that you understand but do not help in solving the problem.
There is a reason why I don't use decorators, thanks. @Nico

Comment: @avihu24 That was just informative, the problem has been solved in the previous comment. You are not pushing the div#cardX element into your DOM before giving it details. You said you were pushing it into the "rest of the code" and the rest of the code is in your function called"appendAmountToCardDetails" , to get it with getElementById the card needs to be pushed into the DOM before this function is called.